# Does Parse's JS client set a timeout?

Tags: parse-platform

Recently I've been running worker machines that are brought up & down to perform tasks against Parse collections. But a small percentage of those machines are never torn down. I understand that NodeJS itself doesn't have a timeout set on connections so for a non-responsive server, my nodejs code may end up sitting there indefinitely, doing nothing and thus my worker machine wouldn't be torn down.

My question is: Does the parse js client have a timeout set?

## Update # 1

Looking through Parse's nodejs client and I saw that they use https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest which doesn't have the concept of timeout:
https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/pull/67
Could this be the culprit when a connection gets lost in limbo while talking to Parse and the code just sits there until a worker timesout?

Comment: parse js client isA Backbone.js.client extension. So, in BB-Underscore, how is the httpClient Timeout set? u can review the src . socketTimeout?? connectionTimeout?? connectionRequestTimeout??  3 lowlevel attr values are involved in this.

Answer (score 0):

So as I discovered, the answer is NO there isn't a default timeout.

I updated the underlying library for Parse JS SDK to provide a timeout:

- https://github.com/ShoppinPal/node-XMLHttpRequest.git

And patched the most current version of parse sdk to use it:

- https://github.com/ShoppinPal/parse-js